# I simpy want to move an image by button click?

Tags: css

i want to move an img by button click. I know this question has been asked a lot, but i couldnt use them.

Heres the relevant HTML:

```
<button class="ggE" (click)="gegenEnemy(chosenHero, actualEnemy);moveFist(); ...
  <div class="col">
    <img id="img" class="fist" src="...">
```

This is the function (typescript):

```
moveFist(): void {
    document.getElementById('img').classList.add('fist');
  }
```

And my css, which makes the picture move from left to right:

```
.fist {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:50px; top:20px;}
  100% {left:450px; top:20px;}
}
```

So why cant i connect it with a button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **validate** your **HTML** code

```
<button class="ggE" onclick="moveFist();">button</button>
<div class="col">
  <img id="img" class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
<div>
```

Edits:

```
function moveFist(){
  
  document.getElementById("img").classList.remove("fist");
  
  // element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
  // Do this instead:
  
  void img.offsetWidth;
  
  document.getElementById("img").classList.add("fist");
}
```

set the **width** of **img** by it's **offset width** that is,
**`img.offsetWidth;`**

**Can you something like this ?**

```js
function moveFist(){
  
  document.getElementById("img").classList.remove("fist");
  
  // element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
  // Do this instead:
  
  void img.offsetWidth;
  
  document.getElementById("img").classList.add("fist");
}
```

```css
img{
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  left:50px;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  top:20px;
}
.fist{
  position:relative;
  animation-name: example;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:50px; top:20px;}
  100% {left:450px; top:20px;}
}
```

```html
<button class="ggE" onclick="moveFist()">button</button>
<div class="col">
  <img id="img" class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
<div>
```

Comment: i dont know, with .toggle it works, idk why. But do you know how i can stop making it move when i load the site?

Thanks !!!

Comment: i added onclick() function in button and added function. then the function moveFist works only click the button.

Comment: Also i added close button `</button>` in html too.

Comment: if yoy get the expected output then don't forgot [to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :). Thanks

Comment: `gegenEnemy(chosenHero, actualEnemy);` is this ?

Comment: Add like this at onclick() event `onclick="gegenEnemy(chosenHero, actualEnemy);moveFist();"`

Comment: yes watch answer on this question so i can show you my code